# Как добавить минуты к дате?

Tags: php

Секунды можно добавить вот так:

```
$time = 10; //добавляем 10 секунд

$new_day_plus1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$new_day_plus1->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$time.'S'));
echo $new_date_do1 = $new_day_plus1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

А как добавить минуты?
http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php тут ничего не нашел, возможно не заметил просто...

Comment: PT12M20S - http://php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.construct.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так добавляются минуты к дате.

```
$minutes_to_add = 5;

$new_day_plus1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$new_day_plus1->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));

echo $new_date_do1 = $new_day_plus1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```